# "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value" in double linked list implementation

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

Valgrind states me two errors that I can not solve. 
I get a "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value" error message in the following function `unplug_set`. Is it because of the `NULL` check? The function should unplug on element from an double linked list.

```
void unplug_set(set * set_to_unplug){
        set * last_set = set_to_unplug->last;
        set * next_set = set_to_unplug->next;
        set_to_unplug->next = NULL;
        set_to_unplug->last = NULL;
148     if(last_set == NULL && next_set == NULL){ // only one element left
          ordered_by_score_set[set_to_unplug->weight] = NULL;
150     }else if(last_set == NULL){ // first set
          next_set->last = NULL;
          ordered_by_score_set[set_to_unplug->weight] = next_set;
        } else if (next_set == NULL) { // last set
          last_set->next = NULL;
        } else { // set in the middle
          last_set->next = next_set;
        next_set->last = last_set;
       }
}
```

The Valgrind command:

```
valgrind --dsymutil=yes --track-origins=yes ./set_program
```

Output:

```
==45085== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==45085==    at 0x100001A2C: unplug_set(set*) (:148)
                          ...
==45085==    by 0x100001294: main (Main.cpp:81)
==45085==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==45085==    at 0xC713: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:274)
==45085==    by 0x63346: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==45085==    by 0x100001E0C: add_set(int, int, unsigned int const*, unsigned short const*, int, unsigned int const*) (:57)
==45085==    by 0x10000127E: main (Main.cpp:39)
==45085==
==45085== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==45085==    at 0x100001A60: unplug_set(set*) (:150)
                          ...
==45085==    by 0x100001294: main (Main.cpp:81)
==45085==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==45085==    at 0xC713: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:274)
==45085==    by 0x63346: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==45085==    by 0x100001E0C: add_set(int, int, unsigned int const*, unsigned short const*, int, unsigned int const*) (:57)
==45085==    by 0x10000127E: main (Main.cpp:39)
```

Comment: Use the valgrind option --track-origins=yes

Comment: It sounds like either `set` instances don't initialise all their members when allocated or list manipulation code doesn't always correctly update next/prev pointers.  Can you post a full, small example which demonstrates this problem?

Comment: I like how every single related link is basically the same title.

Comment: @simonc oh this could be possible. I check this

Comment: @simonc that the solution. Thank you a lot. I have to get better with valgrind.

Comment: The problem is in the `add_set()` code which is not initializing something...see the 0x100001E0C lines in the `valgrind` output.

Answer (score 0):

set_to_unplug argument value is initialized by its constructor using new operator. If no initialization in the constructor, then you have the reason why valgrind complain.

We dont have enough information to answer your problem. post how this function is used. and how the argument value is initialized.